# Not visible data in some slices ZFS after reboot

Tags: zfs

There was a question from a knowledgeable good ZFS file system.
**System: FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE # 0 r286666**
**ZFS filesystem version: 5**

I have a basic ZFS section `zroot`
I created it 2 slice *`zroot/developing`*,`zroot/gocode` and placed there some data.

After the computer restarts, the slices can be seen on the team *`zfs list`* and mount. However, data is not visible there.

In order that the data could be seen should be made *`zfs unmount zroot/developing`* and remount*`zfs mount zroot/developing`*.

How do I fix this problem? 
Who can faced / or know the reason for such behavior of ZFS?

upd: add ext info:

**df -h**

```
Filesystem            Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
zroot/ROOT/default    1,3T    380G    938G    29%    /
devfs                 1,0K    1,0K      0B   100%    /dev
fdescfs               1,0K    1,0K      0B   100%    /dev/fd
procfs                4,0K    4,0K      0B   100%    /proc
fdescfs               1,0K    1,0K      0B   100%    /dev/fd
procfs                4,0K    4,0K      0B   100%    /proc
linprocfs             4,0K    4,0K      0B   100%    /usr/compat/linux/proc
tmpfs                 5,9G    4,0K    5,9G     0%    /tmpfs
zroot/tmp             938G    421M    938G     0%    /tmp
zroot/usr/home        952G     14G    938G     1%    /usr/home
zroot/usr/ports       940G    2,2G    938G     0%    /usr/ports
zroot/usr/src         939G    551M    938G     0%    /usr/src
stuff                 288G     19K    288G     0%    /usr/stuff
stuff/doc             473G    186G    288G    39%    /usr/stuff/doc
stuff/music           408G    121G    288G    30%    /usr/stuff/music
zroot/var/audit       938G     96K    938G     0%    /var/audit
zroot/var/crash       938G    453M    938G     0%    /var/crash
zroot/var/log         938G    3,9M    938G     0%    /var/log
zroot/var/mail        938G    1,3M    938G     0%    /var/mail
zroot/var/tmp         938G    2,0M    938G     0%    /var/tmp
zroot                 938G     69K    938G     0%    /zroot
map -hosts              0B      0B      0B   100%    /net
zroot/gocode          939G    886M    938G     0%    /usr/home/spouk/go
zroot/developing      949G     11G    938G     1%    /usr/home/spouk/spouk.developing
```

**mount**

```
zroot/ROOT/default on / (zfs, NFS exported, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, multilabel)
fdescfs on /dev/fd (fdescfs)
procfs on /proc (procfs, local)
fdescfs on /dev/fd (fdescfs)
procfs on /proc (procfs, local)
linprocfs on /usr/compat/linux/proc (linprocfs, local)
tmpfs on /tmpfs (tmpfs, local)
zroot/tmp on /tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/home on /usr/home (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/ports on /usr/ports (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/usr/src on /usr/src (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
stuff on /usr/stuff (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
stuff/doc on /usr/stuff/doc (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
stuff/music on /usr/stuff/music (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/audit on /var/audit (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/crash on /var/crash (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/log on /var/log (zfs, local, noatime, noexec, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/mail on /var/mail (zfs, local, nfsv4acls)
zroot/var/tmp on /var/tmp (zfs, local, noatime, nosuid, nfsv4acls)
zroot on /zroot (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
map -hosts on /net (autofs)
zroot/gocode on /usr/home/spouk/go (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
zroot/developing on /usr/home/spouk/spouk.developing (zfs, local, noatime, nfsv4acls)
```

**zfs list -t all**

```
    NAME                                                USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
    stuff                                               306G   288G    19K  /usr/stuff
    stuff/doc                                           186G   288G   186G  /usr/stuff/doc
    stuff/music                                         121G   288G   121G  /usr/stuff/music
    zroot                                               410G   938G  68,5K  /zroot
    zroot@25062016                                         0      -  68,5K  -
    zroot@2016.06.25_1138                                  0      -  68,5K  -
    zroot/ROOT                                          380G   938G    96K  none
    zroot/ROOT@25062016                                    0      -    96K  -
    zroot/ROOT@2016.06.25_1138                             0      -    96K  -
    zroot/ROOT/default                                  380G   938G   380G  /
    zroot/ROOT/default@25062016                         264K      -   375G  -
    zroot/ROOT/default@2016.06.25_1138                  264K      -   375G  -
    zroot/developing                                   11,3G   938G  10,9G  /home/spouk/spouk.developing
    zroot/developing@tester_spouk_developing_24062016   410M      -   410M  -
    zroot/developing@250620161042                          0      -  10,9G  -
    zroot/developing@25062016                              0      -  10,9G  -
    zroot/developing@2016.06.25_1138                       0      -  10,9G  -
    zroot/developing@last2016-06-29                    76,5K      -  10,9G  -
    zroot/gocode                                        888M   938G   886M  /home/spouk/go
    zroot/gocode@20160625                                67K      -   809M  -
    zroot/gocode@25062016                                  0      -   809M  -
    zroot/gocode@2016.06.25_1138                           0      -   809M  -
    zroot/gocode@last2016-06-29                         271K      -   886M  -
    zroot/tmp                                           423M   938G   421M  /tmp
    zroot/tmp@25062016                                  389K      -   385M  -
    zroot/tmp@2016.06.25_1138                           386K      -   385M  -
    zroot/usr                                          17,5G   938G    96K  /usr
    zroot/usr@25062016                                     0      -    96K  -
    zroot/usr@2016.06.25_1138                              0      -    96K  -
    zroot/usr/home                                     14,8G   938G  14,1G  /usr/home
    zroot/usr/home@25062016                            1,64M      -  13,9G  -
    zroot/usr/home@2016.06.25_1138                     1,66M      -  13,9G  -
    zroot/usr/ports                                    2,16G   938G  2,16G  /usr/ports
    zroot/usr/ports@25062016                               0      -  2,16G  -
    zroot/usr/ports@2016.06.25_1138                        0      -  2,16G  -
    zroot/usr/src                                       551M   938G   551M  /usr/src
    zroot/usr/src@25062016                                 0      -   551M  -
    zroot/usr/src@2016.06.25_1138                          0      -   551M  -
    zroot/var                                           461M   938G    96K  /var
    zroot/var@25062016                                     0      -    96K  -
    zroot/var@2016.06.25_1138                              0      -    96K  -
    zroot/var/audit                                      96K   938G    96K  /var/audit
    zroot/var/audit@25062016                               0      -    96K  -
    zroot/var/audit@2016.06.25_1138                        0      -    96K  -
    zroot/var/crash                                     453M   938G   453M  /var/crash
    zroot/var/crash@25062016                               0      -   453M  -
    zroot/var/crash@2016.06.25_1138                        0      -   453M  -
    zroot/var/log                                      4,87M   938G  3,93M  /var/log
    zroot/var/log@25062016                              106K      -  4,10M  -
    zroot/var/log@2016.06.25_1138                       111K      -  4,11M  -
    zroot/var/mail                                     1,36M   938G  1,31M  /var/mail
    zroot/var/mail@25062016                                0      -  1,31M  -
    zroot/var/mail@2016.06.25_1138                         0      -  1,31M  -
    zroot/var/tmp                                      2,11M   938G  1,98M  /var/tmp
    zroot/var/tmp@25062016                             38,5K      -  1,99M  -
    zroot/var/tmp@2016.06.25_1138                      38,5K      -  1,99M  -
**zfs get all zroot/developing**
NAME              PROPERTY              VALUE                         SOURCE
zroot/developing  type                  filesystem                    -
zroot/developing  creation              пт июн 24 17:55 2016     -
zroot/developing  used                  11,3G                         -
zroot/developing  available             938G                          -
zroot/developing  referenced            10,9G                         -
zroot/developing  compressratio         1.41x                         -
zroot/developing  mounted               yes                           -
zroot/developing  quota                 none                          default
zroot/developing  reservation           none                          default
zroot/developing  recordsize            128K                          default
zroot/developing  mountpoint            /home/spouk/spouk.developing  local
zroot/developing  sharenfs              off                           default
zroot/developing  checksum              on                            default
zroot/developing  compression           lz4                           inherited from zroot
zroot/developing  atime                 off                           inherited from zroot
zroot/developing  devices               on                            default
zroot/developing  exec                  on                            default
zroot/developing  setuid                on                            default
zroot/developing  readonly              off                           default
zroot/developing  jailed                off                           default
zroot/developing  snapdir               visible                       local
zroot/developing  aclmode               discard                       default
zroot/developing  aclinherit            restricted                    default
zroot/developing  canmount              on                            default
zroot/developing  xattr                 off                           temporary
zroot/developing  copies                1                             default
zroot/developing  version               5                             -
zroot/developing  utf8only              off                           -
zroot/developing  normalization         none                          -
zroot/developing  casesensitivity       sensitive                     -
zroot/developing  vscan                 off                           default
zroot/developing  nbmand                off                           default
zroot/developing  sharesmb              off                           default
zroot/developing  refquota              none                          default
zroot/developing  refreservation        none                          default
zroot/developing  primarycache          all                           default
zroot/developing  secondarycache        all                           default
zroot/developing  usedbysnapshots       410M                          -
zroot/developing  usedbydataset         10,9G                         -
zroot/developing  usedbychildren        0                             -
zroot/developing  usedbyrefreservation  0                             -
zroot/developing  logbias               latency                       default
zroot/developing  dedup                 off                           default
zroot/developing  mlslabel                                            -
zroot/developing  sync                  standard                      default
zroot/developing  refcompressratio      1.41x                         -
zroot/developing  written               76,5K                         -
zroot/developing  logicalused           15,7G                         -
zroot/developing  logicalreferenced     15,2G                         -
zroot/developing  volmode               default                       default
zroot/developing  filesystem_limit      none                          default
zroot/developing  snapshot_limit        none                          default
zroot/developing  filesystem_count      none                          default
zroot/developing  snapshot_count        none                          default
zroot/developing  redundant_metadata    all                           default
```

Comment: Beware that what you call a section is a pool and what you call a slice is a dataset (of the file system type here). You should add the output of "zfs list -t all", "mount", "df -h"  and "zfs get all zroot/developing" to your question.

Comment: @jlliagre update request info

Comment: Why is the mount point configured for the developing file system is /home/spouk/spouk.developing while the current mount point is /usr/home/spouk/spouk.developing ?

Comment: ohh man u right, my error. Ty for point.